# Sound problem in Notification in Emulator

Tags: android, audio, notifications

i wanna play notification sound in emulator, but it is not working;
i do:

```
notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
Uri u = Uri.parse("android.resources://my.package.name/" + R.raw.customsound);
notification.sound = u;
```

customsound is played well with mediaplayer, but in notification it gives nothing except following LogCat:

> 07-29 12:44:36.326: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('/system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg')
>   07-29 12:44:36.396: WARN/AudioService(61): MediaPlayer IOException: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
>   07-29 12:44:36.396: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(61): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
>   07-29 12:44:36.446: WARN/NotificationService(61): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
>   07-29 12:44:36.446: WARN/NotificationService(61):     at com.android.server.NotificationPlayer$CreationAndCompletionThread.run(NotificationPlayer.java:90)
>   07-29 12:03:34.712: WARN/AudioService(61): MediaPlayer IOException: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
notification.sound =Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "Name OF audio store in raw folder");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already tried that way, nothings to seem working, again same exceptions in the LogCat.